# Android tablet gets hot and shuts down

Tags: overheating

I have an Imito android tablet. It gets hot and shuts down. Any have a reason for this and is it fixable?

Comment: If it's in warranty still I'd sent it back, sounds like a hardware fault.

Comment: If there's enough time between "getting warm", "getting hot" and "shut down", and you didn't yet send back the device, you could try a tool like [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat): As soon as the device warms up, start it and set it to save all log to your sd card. There should be alerts logged when it comes to the shutdown which give the reason.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be an app consumes a lot of CPU power and therefore causes the system to overheat. [Use a system monitor to find out any misbehaving apps.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27832)