# How can I monitor and visualize the current resource usage (CPU, Memory, etc.) caused by the running Apps?

Tags: system, resource-monitoring

I am looking for typical per app/process resource usage information (CPU, Memory, etc.). This information is often useful to find and identify misbehaving apps.

**How can I monitor and visualize the current resource usage (CPU, Memory, etc.) caused by the running Apps?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to collect this type of information, I'll be speaking about two that I use on a daily basis as to oversee what's going on with my devices:

### Terminal

Using a terminal application, you are able to run Linux commands like `top` or `ps` that provide information about the currently running processes:

- [ps](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ps.1.html)

  > ps (i.e., process status) displays information about a selection of the active processes.
- [top](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/top.1.html)

  > The top program provides a dynamic real-time view of a running system. It can display system summary information as well as a list of tasks currently being managed by the Linux  kernel.

The terminal I most use is called [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) by Jack Palevich available from Google Play Store.

### Application

There are [several applications](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=system%20information&c=apps) with the sole purpose of providing you with real-time information regarding the processes being executed, detailed information about apps and their system resources usage, system logs or system monitoring:

[Android System Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi) by ElectricSheep available from Google Play Store.

This app presents information divided with 5 tabs:

- Dashboard

  An overview of you device important information: battery usage; Internal Memory used/free; SDCard size and free space; RAM; etc.
- System

  All system information is presented here: OS; Buildinfos; Battery; Memory; Telephony; Networks; Wifi; CPU; Screen; Sensors; Features; JavaProperties; and many more. Just tap over each one to unfold the detailed information.
- Tasks

  Shows the total CPU load and CPU load/memory used for each process. You can tap a process to get more details about it; kill the process or switch to the process.
- Apps

  List of all installed apps, providing means to stop or uninstall an app. If you tap over an app, you have several options like: launch; Manage; Uninstall; etc. Additionally, you are able to see all the useful information about the package itself and in relation to your system, including all permissions he uses.
- Logs

  Provides you with your system logs. If you press "menu" the logs will be saved to your SD  card.

  [image: Android System Info - Dashboard, System, Tasks]

  [image: Android System Info - Apps Logs]

Comment: This app doesn't work on Android 8 :( shows only the "Android System Info" in Tasks tab :(

Comment: Android Terminal Emulator doesn't work with more recent Android versions,  last updated in 2015.  Termux is a more recent one.

Answer (score 0):

**Settings -> Applications -> Application manager -> RUNNING**

shows the memory taken up by running apps.

**Trepn Profiler**

shows CPU taken up by running apps (it has modes average and instantaneous).